Problems in saving NSView with subviews to PDF
I have an NSView with NSImage instances as subviews that all show up correctly on the screen. I want to save them to a PDF file but the subviews are not included.
The routine works well and also saves to PDF. The resulting PDF file contains all that I draw on the NSView, but the NSImage-subviews are only visible on screen but not in the PDF file.
Any suggestions?
NSString* savePath = [self getSavePath];

if (savePath != nil) {
    
    NSData *pdfData = [_myCtDistView dataWithPDFInsideRect:_myCtDistView.bounds];

    if ([pdfData writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES]) {        
        NSLog(@"Saved PDF successfully");        
    } else {        
        NSLog(@"Saved PDF failed");
    }
}

View drawing code:
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
        
    [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
    NSRectFill(self.bounds);

    [self drawBgImage];

}//end of drawRect   

- (void)drawBgImage {
   
    NSImageView *backgroundImageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    backgroundImageView.image = _bgImage;
    backgroundImageView.imageScaling = NSImageScaleProportionallyUpOrDown;

   [self addSubview:backgroundImageView];

}// end of drawBgImage


Was there a particular reason why you are adding the background image in drawRect?

drawRect should draw, nothing else. Don't add subviews from drawRect. Add the image view first and then call dataWithPDFInsideRect. Or draw the image without a NSImageView in drawRect.

Thanks Shim, that was very helpful! I love learning.
